# How to add 2 different composite having different layout on main composite?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to show view which contains 2 `Tree Viewers` and one `Table Viewer`.
It will look as follow,

---

## TreeViewer1         |      TreeViewer2

## -------------TableViewer------------

---

(Sorry as I can't upload the image from my machine due to some restrictions, but the above controls must fill the entire area of the view)

For this I had created one `mainComposite`, which will hold all the controls and which is having `RowLayout` with `SWT.VERTICAL` style.
After that I had created top composite which is going to hold `TreeViewer`1 and `TreeViewer`2, and which is having `Grid layout` with 2 columns.(Where each column will contain one `TreeViewer` resp.)
After that I had created bottom composite which is going to hold TableViewer, and which is again having grid layout with 1 column.

`mainComposite` holds top and bottom composite. The top and bottom composite needs to share mainComposites height equally and both composites needs to acquire entire width of mainComposite.

When I run the program, my controls are coming in order as I want.But they are not acquiring the entire width of the composite.( i.e. they are coming in left corner ).
I tried using different type of layouts but no help.

I tried with the post
http://www.programcreek.com/2012/03/eclipse-rcp-tutorial-5-how-to-layout-your-view-gridlayout-example/
 but didn't work for me since I am having table viewer and not Text.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Mandar

Comment: Some code snippets would help to resolve your issue:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the behavior that I think you're looking for (both trees as well as the table using all available space) by using a bunch of `GridLayouts` with alignments set to `SWT.FILL` and both `grabExcess*Space` parameters set to true.

Try this:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gl_container = new GridLayout(1, false);
    gl_container.horizontalSpacing = 15;
    container.setLayout(gl_container);

    Composite mainComposite = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    mainComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    mainComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    Composite treesComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.NONE);
    treesComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    treesComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    TreeViewer leftTreeViewer = new TreeViewer(treesComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    Tree leftTree = leftTreeViewer.getTree();
    leftTree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    TreeViewer rightTreeViewer = new TreeViewer(treesComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    Tree rightTree = rightTreeViewer.getTree();
    rightTree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    TableViewer bottomTableViewer = new TableViewer(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    bottomTable = bottomTableViewer.getTable();
    bottomTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
}
```

Alternatively, you could try using `FormLayouts`.

Here I specify the locations of things using the "numerator/offset" approach. Where you see numbers like **0/50/100**, those are essentially percentages of the available space. The smaller numbers like **5/-5** are offsets, in pixels, from the positions described by those percentages; they provide a small margin between components.

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gl_container = new GridLayout(1, false);
    gl_container.horizontalSpacing = 15;
    container.setLayout(gl_container);

    Composite mainComposite = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    mainComposite.setLayout(new FormLayout());
    mainComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    Composite treesComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.NONE);
    FormData fd_treesComposite = new FormData();
    fd_treesComposite.bottom = new FormAttachment(50);
    fd_treesComposite.right = new FormAttachment(100);
    fd_treesComposite.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_treesComposite.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    treesComposite.setLayoutData(fd_treesComposite);
    treesComposite.setLayout(new FormLayout());

    TreeViewer leftTreeViewer = new TreeViewer(treesComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    Tree leftTree = leftTreeViewer.getTree();
    FormData fd_leftTree = new FormData();
    fd_leftTree.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
    fd_leftTree.right = new FormAttachment(50, -2);
    fd_leftTree.top = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
    fd_leftTree.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
    leftTree.setLayoutData(fd_leftTree);

    TreeViewer rightTreeViewer = new TreeViewer(treesComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    Tree rightTree = rightTreeViewer.getTree();
    FormData fd_rightTree = new FormData();
    fd_rightTree.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
    fd_rightTree.right = new FormAttachment(100, -5);
    fd_rightTree.top = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
    fd_rightTree.left = new FormAttachment(50, 3);
    rightTree.setLayoutData(fd_rightTree);

    TableViewer bottomTableViewer = new TableViewer(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    bottomTable = bottomTableViewer.getTable();
    FormData fd_bottomTable = new FormData();
    fd_bottomTable.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -5);
    fd_bottomTable.right = new FormAttachment(100, -5);
    fd_bottomTable.top = new FormAttachment(50, 5);
    fd_bottomTable.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
    bottomTable.setLayoutData(fd_bottomTable);
}
```

Comment: Hello @stracka , I am facing one little problem with this approach. When I call the expandAll() or expandToLevel(4) with this code, the tree area gets expanded automatically. And hides the table viewers area. If I didn't call these method, this approach works perfectly for me.

Comment: I added an alternative approach that uses `FormLayout`; it might give you better results when you expand your trees.

Comment: Hello stracka, This solution works better than the previous. And really helpful for my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use in all composites FillLayout. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTFillLayoutSample.htm) is an small example how to use it. Important is to set SWT.VERTICAL/SWT.HORIZONTAL.